# Pandas Expanding into MultiIndex from series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following series provided in CSV files with a flat, unusual data structure. So I'm trying to clean it up and tabulate it / index it correctly in pandas, and I think a MultiIndex is the best way to represent the data.

```
SERVICE 1      NaN
Units          6
Amount         5
Foo            bar
NaN            NaN
SERVICE 2      NaN
Units          6
Amount         22
Foo            bar
NaN            NaN
SERVICE 3      NaN
Units          77
Amount         153
Foo            16
```

and so on.

The indexes in capitals are effectively the level I want to create as the "level 1" of the MultiIndex, with those below it as the "second level". So this would enable accessing data by the "SERVICE" and then by "Units/Amount/Foo" etc.  Not sure the best way to approach this is.

I've used `df[df.index.str.isupper().fillna(False)].index` to provide me with the "level 1" indexes, but I've hit a roadblock on where to go after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the first level with `where` + `ffill`. Then remove the unnecessary rows and set the index. If needed drop the `NaN` entries in the second level

```
df['idx']= df[0].where(df[0].str.contains('SERVICE')).ffill()
df = df[df[0].ne(df.idx)]
df = df.set_index(['idx', 0])
df = df[df.index.get_level_values(1).notnull()]

                    1
idx       0          
SERVICE_1 Units     6
          Amount    5
          Foo     bar
SERVICE_2 Units     6
          Amount   22
          Foo     bar
SERVICE_3 Units    77
          Amount  153
          Foo      16
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, thank you! Had no idea about the `ffill()` method.

Comment: @jbentley yes, it's a shorthand for `fillna(method='ffill')` i.e. forward fill

Comment: @jbentley Also, if the values in column `1` are of a different type for different values of the 1st level, you may instead want to do `df.unstack()` at the end. This allows 'Units' and 'Amount' can be kept as a number instead of the `object` type the above requires. for the entire column.